# function in Gravity Forms to read if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

This snippet for **Gravity Forms** works well with text inputs, verifies that an input is empty and returns the value "Not specified", but appears that it doesn't work with checkboxes.

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission', 'map_input', 10, 5 );
function map_input( $form ) {
  if (  empty($_POST['input_21']) ) {
    $_POST['input_21'] = 'Not specified';
  }
}
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is `Not specified` a “valid” value for your checkbox field? I guess this probably gets kicked in some validation step that comes afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkboxes have a field ID *and* input ID. It sounds like you want to check if no checkbox is checked? Here's an simple way to do that:

```
// Update "123" to your form ID.
add_action( 'gform_pre_submission_123', function( $form ) {

    // The ID of your checkbox field.
    $field_id = 1;

    /** @var GF_Field $field */
    $checkbox_field = GFAPI::get_field( $form, $field_id );
    $value = $checkbox_field->get_value_submission( array() );

    // Just so you can see the data that is returned. Delete this once you have.
    print_r( $value );

    $value = array_filter( $value );
    if ( empty( $value ) ) {
        // Do what you want to.
    }

} );
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks!, It works perfectly! Best regards!